# sizeof - convert a pointer to an array

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the sizeof(a pointer pointing to an array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

I have the following code

```
int myfunc(char *arr)
{
const int sizearr = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof(char);
}
```

This yields the size of the pointer, not the size of the char array[17] I passed to the function.

I know that I may use strlen and solve the problem, but is there any way to convert the char*arr pointer back to the char array[17] I passed to the function in order to use the sizeof(char array[17]) ?

Comment: FYI size of a char is 1. So that doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pass an array of 17 chars, you need to pass it by reference (C++ only):

```
int myfunc(char (&arr)[17])
{
    unsigned int const sizearr = sizeof arr;
    // ...
}
```

Or make a template to deduce the size:

```
template <unsigned int sizearr>
int myfunc(char (&arr)[sizearr])
{
    // ...
}
```

In C, you cannot pass arrays as arguments at all, so it is *your* responsibility to communicate the array size separately.

*Update:* As @David suggests, you can fix the array type in C by passing a pointer to the array:

```
int myfunc(char (*arr)[17])
{
    unsigned int const sizearr = sizeof *arr;
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    char s[17];
    return myfunc(&s);
}
```

Comment: +1 the way to recover the size is never to loose it :) In C you can do basically the same if you pass the array by pointer (but the size will be fixed at compile time!)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Good point about passing the array by address. I added that!

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such way. But in C++ you can make function template parametrized by array size and pass array by reference:

```
template <size_t size> void myfunc(char (&arr)[size])
{
   for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) std::cout << arr[i];
}

// Usage
char array[] = "My char array";
myfunc(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

There is no such way. The type `char *` does not contain any information about the "source", i.e. the array. This is why it's said that the array "decays" into a pointer; the pointer has less information than the array.

<sub>Also, `sizeof (char)` is 1.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Not really, because once the array has [decayed to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) all information regarding its "original" form has been lost. You can always cast the pointer to a `char[17]` but that's bad practice.

If you really need to have an array, change the function signature to accept an array.